# What is Azure Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have 2 Powershell applications sitting on the desk of a server I have inherited.

What is the difference between "Windows Powershell" and "Microsoft Azure Powershell"?

Answer (score 1):

**Windows PowerShell** is a new command shell and scripting language for Windows. You can think of it as a really complicated version of the command prompt designed for repeatable tasks.

**Windows Azure PowerShell** is used extensively in the Microsoft HDInsight articles because it makes it easier to use Hadoop remotely from your workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure Powershell is specifically targeted for Cloud (MS Azure operations)

As far as Azure Powershell Modules are installed, you can interact with the Cloud (MS Azure Operations) from the Windows Powershell Application.

Answer (score -1):

A set of Azure PowerShell cmdlets allow you to manage Azure resources from PowerShell. With Azure PowerShell, you can learn and start automating quickly, and it offers powerful features.